# All possible combinations of vectors within a given matrix - R

Tags: r

Similar to a previous question. I getting an error message saying "Error in Data[, j] : subscript out of bounds" and I am unable to see why.

I am only trying to take the products of all vectors in a given matrix and store within a 3-dimensional array to test for significance of interaction terms within a multiple regression. I have provided a sample piece of code and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
a     <- array( 1 , c( 3 ,1 ) )
b     <- array( 2 , c( 3 ,1 ) )
d     <- array( 3 , c( 3 ,1 ) )
Data  <- array( c( a , b , d ) , c( 3 , 3 ) )
#
Sdata   <-  array( dim( Data ) , c( 2 , 1 ) )
    Q       <-  ( Sdata[ 2 , 1 ] * ( Sdata[ 2 , 1 ] - 1 ) ) / 2
    #
    Combos  <-  array( 0 , c( Sdata[ 1 , 1 ] , Sdata[ 2 , 1 ] , Sdata[ 2 , 1 ] - 1 ) )
    #
    Scombos <-  array( dim( Combos ) , c( 3 , 1 ) )
    #
   for( k in 1 : Scombos[ 2 , 1 ] - 1 ){
      for( j in k + 1 : Scombos[ 2 , 1 ]  ){
        Combos[ , j , k ]   <-  Data[ , j ] * Data[ , k ]                 
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please **do not** include `rm(list=ls())` in your example code!

Comment: Why don't you let your regression function do this work for you. particularly the `*`. You can read about it in `?formula`.

Comment: please http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Seth is right that you should use the formula interface to `lm(...)` to generate the interaction terms. But since you asked how to create every possible product of columns pairwise, here is one way.

```
df     <- data.frame(Data)
comb   <- data.frame(combn(colnames(df),2),stringsAsFactors=F)
result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(comb,function(x)df[,x[1]]*df[,x[2]]))
colnames(result) <- sapply(comb,paste,collapse=".")
result
#      X1.X2 X1.X3 X2.X3
# [1,]     2     3     6
# [2,]     2     3     6
# [3,]     2     3     6
```